# Java: How to have if statements read both numbers and words

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program of mine have `if` statements understand both words and numbers, now the converting doubles to strings, and Strings to doubles is not a problem, but where the problem lies is that when the user enters `"restart"` the program will not go to my restart menu (`restart01();`), it'll be going to either `} else if (Grd1<5) {` or `} else {`, please help me...
Here's my program (more in depth, when you see the full thing), but this is one of 5 parts (that look alike) where I'm having the program...

```
public static void Gdr1() {
        try {
            System.out.print("[Code: Gdr1]  Grade 1: %");
            Scanner gdr1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Z = gdr1.next();
            Z = Double.toString(Grd1);
            Grd1 = Double.parseDouble(Z);
            if ((Grd1<100)&&(Grd1>=5)) {
                Gdr2();
            } else if ((Grd1>=100)&&(Grd1<125)) {
                System.out.println("    System> Great Job "+Stu+"!");
                Gdr2();
            } else if (Grd1<5) {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, the lowest grade I am allowed to compute is 5...");
                Gdr1();
            } else if (Z.equalsIgnoreCase("restart")) {
                restart01(); 
                //This is the only part that doesn't work...
            } else {
                System.out.println("("+Z+") cannot be resolved in my system...");
                Gdr1();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Now everything does work in the program, besides for when the End-User's input = `" restart"`, I know some of the code in the program seems complicated, but it does work (most of it), can anyone help me try to figure this out, it's for my portfolio at my school due latest by 1/25/2017 @ 11:59 pm.

The things like `Z` (constant String), `""+Stu+""` (variable input), and `[Code: Gdr1]` (for restart menu) are there for other purposes in the program that require them to be there, well except for `[Code: Gdr1]` that's there only for the restart menu...

Comment: I've fixed your tags for you. Java is not JavaScript, and right there in big type on the [tag:xcode] tag it says "USAGE NOTE: Use this tag only for questions about the Xcode IDE itself..."

Comment: Stop the recursion and use a while loop! Look at NoDataFound's answer. That pretty much does exactly what you need. No try/catch or recursion.

Comment: Stick to the naming conventions! Variable names should start with a lowercase character.

Comment: the try catch, is a method, and I have to have at least 6 methods in my portfolio, the method is also used for different parts of the program.  the only problem is the `if else` statement..

Comment: I also do not know how to use loops (`do while`s), my teacher tried explaing it to me, in a very "easy to understand" way, and I still dont get it, he showed code of it, and i still dont understand it, I use the `if else` statement to act like a loop stantment, without the exact loop words.

Comment: A while loop will help you execute code as long as a condition is satisfied. It checks the condition, then if it's true execute the block of code; once done, it checks again the condition, etc. Once the condition isn't satisfied anymore, execution continues after the code block. For example : `int i = 0; while (i < 10) { i++; }; System.out.println(i)`. here the condition is that `i` is lesser than `10`. As long as it is true, we will increment `i` (`i++`). At some point `i` will be `10`, and the condition won't be satisfied anymore : `i++` won't be executed and instead `i` (10) will be printed

Comment: I understand (sorta) of what your saying, but I dont know how to use it in the way that i need to...

Comment: @ShaeNoble well I suppose you want to process all the text you receive from the user, so instead of calling your function again each time you've processed a part of it, you should instead use a while loop which condition is "I haven't read the whole text the user entered" and the code block process one part of the user input. With the use of a `Scanner` you should get this kind of code : `while (scanner.hasNext()) { String token = scanner.next(); /*do something with the token*/ }`

Comment: i was saying i have to have 6 methods in my program, because it looked like you took away the method and kept only what you inputed as the main function (if you understand what im saying), but i can see that your just editting what i typed (the `if else` statements), anyway, my program only processes one part at a time, and checks what the user inputs each way.  because  if the users 7 input devices do not link up to a correct equal value, than the program tells the user that there was an error with the inputted devices, so it than restarts the program at `Gdr1();`...

Comment: "i can see that your just editting what i typed" what? I can't do that. I did edit my comments a little bit though, mainly to add other informations or correct my syntax. I didn't intend my answer to be a `main` function. I didn't add the method signature, but it was indeed intended to be your `Grd1` function. Look, I'll try to implement your code in my way in http://ideone.com and get back to you, you'll tell me if it does what you need.

Comment: no, what i ment was when i said "i can see that your just editting what i typed" was that you made suggestion on how to edit what my code was...sorry for the cunfusion

Comment: No problem. I replied to your comment on my answer with a link to an ideone.com snippet. If you scroll down under the code, you'll see the user input and the result of the execution. You can edit the code to your preference to see how it works or see if you can get it to do exactly what you need. Hope it helps ! I'm leaving the computer for now so I won't be able to help you for some time, but I'll make sure to check if you have any other questions.

Comment: Than you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Z = gdr1.next();
Z = Double.toString(Grd1);
```

You read from the scanner, but then directly overwrite the value you just read with the second line, effectively discarding it and instead using the value your `static Double Grd1` was initialized with.

Removing this second line would solve your immediate problem, but then you will encounter another problem : now `Z` will sometimes be the "restart" `String`, and the next line's `Double.parseDouble(Z)` will fail.

As Ninad Shaha mentionned in his answer, you should check whether the `String` is "restart" before attempting to parse it as a `Double`. As NoDataFound mentionned in his answer, it would also be more elegant to check if the next token to be read by the `Scanner` is a `Double` beforehand.

In conclusion, here's how I would do it :

```
System.out.print("[Code: Gdr1]  Grade 1: %");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    // it's a Double
    Double d = scanner.nextDouble();
    /*
      conditions based on the double
    */
} else if (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // it's not a Double, so it may be "restart"
    String s = scanner.next();
    if ("restart".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
        restart01();
    } else {
        System.out.println("("+s+") cannot be resolved in my system...");
        Gdr1();
    }
}
// else we've read everything, we're done
```

Other notes :

- Your naming conventions are terrible and won't help you debugging your code. You've got 3 grd1 / Grd1 : a function, a scanner and a static Double variable. Take the time to correctly name your variables, it will help you in the long run.
- I don't think you have any reason to use static variables here, so you should avoid them. It may be hard to understand and manage the scope of your variables at first, but it's a necessary skill.
- You should also avoid using recursion when it doesn't make sense. Here it won't be problematic, but if you keep this habit you'll soon encounter your first `StackOverflowError`.
- there's no reason to catch exceptions if you're not going to do anything with them. You should instead modify your method's signature to declare what exceptions it can throw (`Exception` if you're lazy and your IDE can't help, but specific subclass are better : more informative to the people calling your method, plus your code won't compile anymore if you've added an operation that raises a new kind of error)

Comment: my teacher told me, and I edit the names of it, so that I know where everything is, I shape my java programs the way I program my CMD programs.  I use lots of methods, and the way i use them, i wont get a `StackOverflowError` I shape my programs as I go, and when I get error (cause I've gotten many of them) I re-shape the program to run.  whether than mean only one part or the entire thing, I do that so I can clearly see what everything is doing.  a lot of my programs use many methods, and converters, so knowing what one Convertion leads to another, helps me know my entire program...

Comment: I posted only one part of a 7,000 line program, and those same 23 lines are repeated 4 times in the program, and 1 time which has the same error as the one above is a 85 line bit.  all of them lead up to another part of my program, I didnt want to copy and paste a 7,000 line program in a question if I only had a question with one peice of it...

Comment: `a 7,000 line program` oh god... `those same 23 lines are repeated 4 times` whyyyy? `a 85 line bit` that's not what I call a "bit". Seriously if it works good for you, but those are all very bad practices. A class of 200 lines is a big class, a function of 50 lines is a big function, and you should strive to DRY (do not repeat yourself)

Comment: Now don't take my advices/critics too harshly, I've been coding in Java for more than 10 years and being paid for it for more than 5 years. Once you're in the industry, you'll understand that writing code that is easy to read, especially by other people, is one of the most important part of your job. We all start somewhere and I don't expect you to get perfect standard practices just by reading my answer, but you don't need to justify yourself about by remarks. Take what you can and make your program work, I'm not your teacher ;)

Comment: sorry, and there of different classes, so nothing really repeats itself, i have constants interpret other constants, so that other parts of my program can read those different constants, and be used in other classes. i wish the whole worked as well as i wish it did, the only part that keeps failing is when trying to read the input `"restart"`, that is what fails some parts of the program...

Comment: For a rather quick fix, don't use your scanner's `.next()` method directly but rather check if what it will return could be a double or a string. if it's a `Double`, use the scanner's `.nextDouble()` instead of `.next()`, which removes the need for `Double.parseDouble(str)`, then apply your current conditions. if it's not a `Double`, use `.next()` and check if it's "restart"

Comment: @ShaeNoble check [this](http://ideone.com/B30XuP) out. Obviously it's not exactly what you need because I don't have your exact specs, but hopefully it does some of the thing you need in a simpler way and will help you understand a few things I wrote.

Comment: actually this makes a lot of sence, so i delete `Double.parseDouble(str)` and add `Double` to `.next()` correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
if (scanner.hasNextDouble())
  double d = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

There are other method for other types and if you want to loop over tokens, you may try hasNext:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  if (scanner.hasNextDouble())
    double d = scanner.nextDouble();
  } else {
    String s = scanner.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: NoDataFound, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Scanner posses several method to check the input to tell if the next token would be a number (double) or not.

Comment: Please look at the answer to my question, it says what i wanted to say in this little comment box...

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you first check whether input is string 'restart' or not and if not then parse it to double. like

```
if (Z.equalsIgnoreCase("restart")) {
                restart01();
            } else {
Grd1 = Double.parseDouble(Z);
            if ((Grd1<100)&&(Grd1>=5)) {
                Gdr2();
            } else if ((Grd1>=100)&&(Grd1<125)) {
                System.out.println("    System> Great Job "+Stu+"!");
                Gdr2();
            } else if (Grd1<5) {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, the lowest grade I am allowed to compute is 5...");
                Gdr1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ninad Shaha, I tried doing that, and my program read everything as if it were `= "restart"`, but thanks anyway...